# Distinguishing between different wxSpinCtrlDouble events

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

Is there a way to distinguish between different events generated by the wxSpinCtrlDouble?
From wxWidgets documentation:

> Event macros:
>   EVT_SPINCTRLDOUBLE(id, func):
>   Generated whenever the numeric value of the spin control is changed, that is, when the up/down spin button is clicked, when ENTER is pressed, or the control loses focus and the new value is different from the last.

So in my case (wxMSW, wxWidgets 3.1.0) wxSpinCtrlDouble generates an event when the up/down spin button is clicked *and* when the control loses focus. It would be convenient to handle only events from the spin button.

**Update**

Code:

```
#include <wx/spinctrl.h>
#include <wx/wx.h>

class TestSpin : public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit();
    void OnEvent(wxSpinDoubleEvent&);
    wxTextCtrl *mText;
};

DECLARE_APP(TestSpin)
IMPLEMENT_APP(TestSpin)

bool TestSpin::OnInit()
{
    wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "", wxDefaultPosition,
                                 wxSize(190, 210));
    frame->Show(true);

    wxSpinCtrlDouble *spin = new wxSpinCtrlDouble(frame, wxID_ANY, "1.0", 
                                                  wxPoint(10, 10), wxSize(150, 20),
                                                  wxSP_ARROW_KEYS | wxALIGN_RIGHT,
                                                  1.0, 10.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    spin->Bind(wxEVT_SPINCTRLDOUBLE, &TestSpin::OnEvent, this);

    mText = new wxTextCtrl(frame, wxID_ANY, "", wxPoint(10, 50), wxSize(150, 110),
                           wxTE_MULTILINE | wxTE_READONLY);

    return true;
}

void TestSpin::OnEvent(wxSpinDoubleEvent&)
{
    mText->AppendText("event\n");
}
```

[Here is a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KU5M.png)
This is what I got after clicking "up" spin button (one time) and clicking on the wxTextCtrl (one time). So when I press "up" button it changes the value from 1 to 2 and generates an event. Then I click on the wxTextCtrl, wxSpinCtrlDouble loses focus and generates the event twice for some reason.

If I simply click on the text region of the wxSpinCtrlDouble and on the wxTextCtrl after that, it also generates two events (the value hasn't even changed in this case).

Also, there is no reaction to ENTER.

**Update II**

After suggestion of [avariant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6584878/avariant), here are events that work in my case:

```
#include <wx/spinctrl.h>
#include <wx/wx.h>

class TestSpin : public wxApp
{
    virtual bool OnInit();
    void OnSpinEvent(wxSpinEvent&);
    void OnTextEvent(wxCommandEvent&);
    void OnEnterEvent(wxCommandEvent&);
    wxTextCtrl *mText;
};

DECLARE_APP(TestSpin)
IMPLEMENT_APP(TestSpin)

bool TestSpin::OnInit()
{
    wxFrame *frame = new wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, "", wxDefaultPosition,
                                 wxSize(190, 210));
    frame->Show(true);

    wxSpinCtrlDouble *spin = new wxSpinCtrlDouble(frame, wxID_ANY, "1.0",
                                                  wxPoint(10, 10), wxSize(150, 20),
                                                  wxSP_ARROW_KEYS | wxALIGN_RIGHT |
                                                  wxTE_PROCESS_ENTER,
                                                  1.0, 20.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    spin->Bind(wxEVT_SPIN, &TestSpin::OnSpinEvent, this);
    spin->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT, &TestSpin::OnTextEvent, this);
    spin->Bind(wxEVT_TEXT_ENTER, &TestSpin::OnEnterEvent, this);

    mText = new wxTextCtrl(frame, wxID_ANY, "", wxPoint(10, 50), wxSize(150, 110),
                           wxTE_MULTILINE | wxTE_READONLY);

    return true;
}

void TestSpin::OnSpinEvent(wxSpinEvent&)
{
    mText->AppendText("spin event\n");
}

void TestSpin::OnTextEvent(wxCommandEvent&)
{
    mText->AppendText("text event\n");
}

void TestSpin::OnEnterEvent(wxCommandEvent&)
{
    mText->AppendText("enter event\n");
}
```

[Here is the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y00wK.png) I got this after typing '0' next to '1' (text event), clicking "up" (text event + spin event), and pressing ENTER.

Well, there is probably no need to have so many events. But at least now there is a choice (I'll probably go with the text event, as it does what's needed: generates an event when the value is changed; one can add one more check in the code if the value is indeed different, i.e., for example, adding '0' symbol at the end of a fractional part does not change the value).

I don't know, however, if it works on other platforms (or other wxWidgets versions).

Comment: the documentation says that the event is generated on the losing focus when the value is different. Are you saying that in you case the value is the same and the event is still generated?

Comment: @Igor: Yep, the example is added.

Comment: Which OS you are testing it on?

Comment: @Igor: Windows 10.

Comment: The documentation on wxSpinCtrl state that you can, on some platforms, bind to the wxSpinButton events which include `EVT_SPIN_UP` and `EVT_SPIN_DOWN`.
Whether these events can be used from wxSpinCtrlDouble, it doesn't say but it's worth trying.

Comment: @avariant Wow thanks, it worked! Didn't test on other platforms, however. Interestingly, `EVT_TEXT` and `EVT_TEXT_ENTER` also work in my case. The code is added.